# how get value from html combo box in asp.net code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm unable to get the selected value from combo box in asp.net. I'm using the HTML combo box in server side coding by adding id and runat="server" and using bootstrap property. How to get the value of a combo box in a button click

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Size</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5 selectContainer">

            <select class="form-control" name="size" runat="server" id="Combobox">
                <option value="">Choose a size</option>
                <option value="s">Small (S)</option>
                <option value="m">Medium (M)</option>
                <option value="l">Large (L)</option>
                <option value="xl">Extra large (XL)</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

code behind


        string value = Combobox.Items.ToString();
```

Comment: What do you expect `Combobox.Items.ToString()` to return? It returns the full-type-name of the `ListItemCollection` type which is `"System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection"`. What do you want instead ?

Comment: i want selected item value of combox in string variable..in code behind

Comment: You have dynamically added this `<select>` block or it is a static control?

Comment: its static items..i want to use it like combo box of ajax controller. i want to use it for select city field. where we can add city which is not exist in items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In codebehind a html-`select` with `runat=server` is a [`HtmlSelect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Items`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect.items(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a [`ListItemCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can use the [`SelectedIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string selectedItemValue = null;
string selectedItemText  = null;
if(Combobox.SelectedIndex >= 0)
{
    ListItem selectedItem = Combobox.Items[Combobox.SelectedIndex];
    selectedItemValue = selectedItem.Value;
    selectedItemText  = selectedItem.Text;
}
```

or use the [`HtmlSelect.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect.value(v=vs.110).aspx) property which does the same:

```
string selectedItemValue = Combobox.Value; // String.Empty if no item selected
```

Comment: `Combobox.Value` should have given him the result.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with `RadComboBox`. I'll just add that in case anyone gets confused.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET is so called server side code, whilst HTML is client side code. This means there is no direct connection between HTML and ASP.NET, besides the fact that ASP.NET generates the HTML and sends it back to te client.

In order to be able to get the value from the select box, you should either use an AJAX request to post the value to the server as soon as the selection changes, or force the user to post a form.

Since you appear to be creating a size selection, I think using the AJAX-method should be the best way.